# Panels view settings - how to preprocess the 'more' link

Tags: views, panels

I have block views added to a panel, and the panel is set to display the 'more' link. How can I change the text for this link?

Answer (score 2):

Change the text of the link in the views module. On your views block admin page. Click on more link and change text there

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks very much for your reply. I think I've given you the wrong idea here though, sorry. In the panel settings popup, there are a number of options, eg. "override title", "display a more link". It's the 'more' link that's output from the Panel, rather than the 'More' link from the view, that I want to preprocess. The reason being, that in each instance that the view is used in a panel, it can be given a  URL etc.

Comment: All these years later, this still seems to be an issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/1000146